# Update - What is the quickest way to get to System Update?

Tags: updates, system

I am obviously new to Ubuntu. I keep digging all over to get to Update. I ususally seem to get it running. I am on limited bandwidth and don't want to waste time. Can I put this directly in the side bar some how?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Unity, when Update Manager is open, right click; lock to panel.  You can also schedule updates to happen semi automatically in update settings.
This will not save bandwidth though, you will use what you use, maybe change the schedule in update settings to notify only, then you will have greater control.

I hope this helps.